# Splitting strings separated by a comma and a white space in spark using scala

Tags: string, scala, apache-spark

I am trying to read a text file with the following format

```
1980, Jan, Wednesday
1982, Feb, Monday
1987, March, Thursday
```

I tried to separate each string with a comma and a space with the following code:

```
val line = sc.textFile("file.txt") 
val lineMap = line.map(x => x.split("[,]+"))
```

But this gives `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Use `.trim` after the split or user `,\s` for split

Comment: I tried `val lineMap = line.map(x => x.split("\\s"))` . But did not work.

Comment: It should be `",\\s"`. Could you give that a try? @precision

Comment: @sai,  I tried `val lineMap = line.map(x => x.split(", \\s"))` but no luck.

Comment: There should be no space between `,` and `\\s`. See: https://imgur.com/a/mi1waOa

Comment: can you just update your question with full stacktrace of the exception

Comment: @sai, `val lineMap = line.map(x => x.split(",\\s"))` this code is working. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TLDR**
Use:

```
val line = sc.textFile("file.txt") 
val lineMap = line.map(x => x.split(",\\s"))
```

See: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0yXd9.jpg